# Block user input on interactive shell using "cat /dev/ttyS0"

Tags: shell, input, user-input

I created an update routine for my device. The update process can be started using the serial console, SSH, telnet, a webserver or a REST API. Once the update started, I want to block all user input from all sources until the update is done and the device reboots. Killing SSH, telnet, the webserver and the REST server is easy, but I also want to block the input on the serial console.

So for that I have the following situation:

- The user connects using the serial interface on `/dev/ttyS0` / `/dev/console`.
- If that shell session is closed, inittab respawns it
- Once the upgrade starts I don't want the user to input anything on the console, so I'd like to block the input for that shell session.

I found that if I `cat /dev/ttyS0` or `cat /dev/console` I can "steal" the input away from the shell, thus blocking input. And if I do `(cat /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/null) &` I can do that in the background and without seeing the input.

Is this method ok? Is there any reason why I shouldn't do that? Is there any better way?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please clarify what the actual problem is you're trying to fix. (You almost certainly don't need to block all input to the console)

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I want to do. While the update runs, I really want to block all input from the user. The device is used by rather non-tech-savy users that, because of legacy reasons, have root access to the shell of the device. I really don't want any of these users to be able to abort the update and thus send the device to an undefined state. I know they can still pull the power chord, but apart from that I'd like to block all user input.

Comment: @Dakkaron The point is you don't want them to abort the update. Unless you're worried about them sending an explicit kill command, that means you don't want them hitting `^C` to stop the update. That's easier to accomplish by making _the update process_ not depend on terminal input, rather than making sure terminal input cannot do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest temporarily changing the `init` configuration so the shell isn't active for a moment.

Since you mention `inittab`, I'll assume you're using `sysvinit`. With that, you can do so by changing the `inittab` config file, and then running `init q` (which causes `init` to reread its configuration file and update internal state). Depending on the version of `sysvinit` and of the shell that's running on your serial console, you may also need to kill the shell itself explicitly.